# How can the channel be closed on connection error using SimpleChannelPool in netty?

Tags: java, netty

I am trying to use connection pooling in netty, but I am having issues writing some of the error handling. My original code had something like the following:

```
ChannelFuture connectFuture = bootstrap.connect(...);
connectFuture.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE_ON_FAILURE);
```

However, `ChannelPool.acquire` returns a `Future<Channel>`. This means on operation failure, there's no access to the channel, so I'm not aware of a way to close it. Is it important to close the failed channel? I assume it may still hold onto some system resources, even if it wasn't able to connect.

I think the relevant code is in the netty class `SimpleChannelPool` in `notifyConnect`:

```
    private void notifyConnect(ChannelFuture future, Promise<Channel> promise) throws Exception {
        if (future.isSuccess()) {
            Channel channel = future.channel();
            handler.channelAcquired(channel);
            if (!promise.trySuccess(channel)) {
                // Promise was completed in the meantime (like cancelled), just release the channel again
                release(channel);
            }
        } else {
            promise.tryFailure(future.cause());
        }
    }
```

Here we can see the promise returned to the caller is failed, but the channel is not propagated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being very simple, you just need to override SimpleChannelPool.connectChannel()` and add the listener there.